# SLD vendor option "follow line" not working

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I am creating an SLD in QGIS to be used in GeoServer. 
I set up the style with color, thickness, etc in QGIS and then saved it out to an SLD. 
QGIS doesn't preserve the label rules so I borrowed some from the SLD cookbook. 
Everything except the following seems to be working:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Optimized and styled label</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>SLD Cook Book: Optimized and styled label</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <se:LineSymbolizer>
                        <se:Stroke>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">white</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Stroke>
                    </se:LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>ST_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <Font>
                                <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="font-size">6</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                            </Font>
                            <LabelPlacement>
                                 <LinePlacement>
                                    0
                                 </LinePlacement>
                            </LabelPlacement>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">#383534</CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                            <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                            <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                            <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
                            <VendorOption name="group">yes</VendorOption>
                            <VendorOption name="spaceAround">30</VendorOption>
                            <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">.05</VendorOption>
                        </Label>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>`
```

This comes out like so:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

Are the vendor options not configured correctly?

I checked out GeoServer's site on curved lines and everything seems to be in order.

Comment: VendorOption is something supported by a vendor (provider of software), so it's quite probable that if GeoServer is the vendor in this case, that the 'option' won't be supported in QGIS and vice versa

Comment: @nmtoken The other vendor options seem to be working.

Comment: Yes, but the same comment applies, vendor options are not part of the standard so may not work; just because some work doesn't mean that all will do, or will do in the same way...